# Check if string is UUID

Tags: bash, shell, uuid

I am trying to test whether a string `$uuid` is a UUID. I have written this script but for some reason it is not working:

```
uuid="7632f5ab-4bac-11e6-bcb7-0cc47a6c4dbd"
if [[ $uuid =~ ^\{?[A-Z0-9]{8}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{12}\}?$ ]]; then
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false"
fi
```

Comment: You made a mistake on your regular expression. See my newly edited answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your regular expression doesn't accept lowercase letters as valid. Here is a fixed version:

```
#!/bin/bash
uuid="7632f5ab-4bac-11e6-bcb7-0cc47a6c4dbd"
if [[ $uuid =~ ^\{?[A-F0-9a-f]{8}-[A-F0-9a-f]{4}-[A-F0-9a-f]{4}-[A-F0-9a-f]{4}-[A-F0-9a-f]{12}\}?$ ]]; then
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false"
fi
```

First of all, you only really need to be searching `A-F` not `A-Z` because UUIDs contain hex digits.

Notice the addition of `a-f` in each character class. Your version will reject any UUID that is printed in lowercase. This new version works fine for me now. An alternative solution is to only use an uppercase UUID, instead of the lowercase one that you have. Your `[A-Z0-9]` classes have for those reasons been replaced with `[A-F0-9a-f]`.

See the post by [Ekeyme Mo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4988506/ekeyme-mo) for safety considerations.

Answer (score 15):

The hyphens don't really mean anything; a UUID is simply a 128-bit value, and the conventional display uses the 8-4-4-4-12 grouping, but that's not *required*. This means that as long as you have 32 hex digits after removing the `-`, it's a UUID.

```
uuid="7632f5ab-4bac-11e6-bcb7-0cc47a6c4dbd"
if [[ ${uuid//-/} =~ ^[[:xdigit:]]{32}$ ]]; then
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false"
fi
```

Comment: Works. It's probably worth to quote ${uuid//-/}, isn't it ?

Comment: Inside `[[...]]`, parameter expansions aren't subject to word-splitting or pathname expansion , which are the two reasons to quote them.

Answer (score 6):

It is safer to pre-save the pattern into a variable in bash `=~` clause to avoid unpredictable escaping in bash.

```
uuid="7632f5ab-4bac-11e6-bcb7-0cc47a6c4dbd"
pattern='^\{?[A-Z0-9a-z]{8}-[A-Z0-9a-z]{4}-[A-Z0-9a-z]{4}-[A-Z0-9a-z]{4}-[A-Z0-9a-z]{12}\}?$'

if [[ "$uuid" =~ $pattern ]]; then
    echo "true" 
else
    echo "false" 
fi
```

Comment: more safe -> safer (a grammatical detail).  But in general escaping will happen anyway when `$pattern` is used, e.g. if you use it inside backticks.  Anyway +1 for quoting `$uuid`, always quote variables to be safe.

Comment: If i execute this script it returns "false". I'm using bash 4.3.46 on linux.

Comment: normal, the first and last `{` must be escaped, I edited